# Firewall / visited websites logger

Tags: http, url, networking, browser, firewall

I have a firewall implementation and I want to log all the websites visited on the machine. So when the user enters an address in the browser(any browser) or clicks a link to be able to log the visited address. 
 The problem is that I want to log only the visited address and NOT the other resources requested by the page (ads, iframes, Google stats and so on). Is there a method to do this by looking at the HTTP or TCP headers? Or any other method.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain how you have implemented the firewall? Not the code, but the basic idea

Comment: It is a packet content filtering app, intercepts sent and received packets by MSTCP, checks if a packet is a HTTP packet, reads the data contained in the packet and by looking at the HTTP headers (at the GET and HOST headers) logs what addresses are requested. So this way it can block a HTTP address by its URL and not only by IP. 
 The problem is that I want to make a visited websites history, but to log only the actual visited addresses and discard other resources requested by the browser for that specific address.

Answer (score 0):

A possible method would be to use "transparent proxying" : Have the firewall automatically transfer all out-bound HTTP connections to a proxy. You'll find the desired information in the proxy's log.

Answer (score 0):

A somehow easier method I found was to use Microsoft® Active Accessibility® and to read the URL from the browser's address bar. But this is tricky in other ways: you have to take into consideration multiple browsers UI layout(at least the most popular ones) and also the differences between versions of the same browser. Some browsers or browser versions have limited support for MSAA and don't expose all the controls (e.g Opera 10.50-10.51, altghough  this was fixed in 10.52).